# Calling Groovy code from Kotlin and passing a Closure as an argument

Tags: jenkins, kotlin, groovy

I am writing some code for generating Jenkins jobs and I am using Kotlin for the logic to generate the Jenkins jobs.  The Jenkins plugin I am using is the [Jenkins Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) plugin which is written in Groovy to generate the jobs.  I am having trouble setting the `definition` parameter when calling from the Kotlin code to the Groovy code due to not knowing how to create an appropriate groovy.lang.Closure object.

Here my my Kotlin code:

```
val pipelineJob = dslFactory.pipelineJob("my-job")
// pipelineJob.definition(JOB_DEFINITION_GOES_HERE)  <-- this is the part I can't figure out
```

Here is the code in Groovy that I am trying to port to work in Kotlin:

```
    dslFactory.pipelineJob("my-job").with {
      definition {
        cps {
          script("deleteDir()")
          sandbox()
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the [definition](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/jobs/WorkflowJob.groovy#L17) of the method I am calling:

```
void definition(@DslContext(WorkflowDefinitionContext) Closure definitionClosure) {
```

---

Other Links:
[DslFactory](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/DslFactory.groovy)